# How to remove / delete the table from the TableList POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using a template docx file to fill the data on each table, but in some cases I don't want same table, is there anyway using which XWPFTable can be deleted / removed?

Comment: You could also take a look at a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968813/how-to-remove-tables-and-paragraphs-containing-data-from-docx-in-java-using-apac). If the answer below solves your problem, please accept it with a green mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
int position = document.getPosOfTable( table );
document.removeBodyElement( position );
```

Here is an example, in which you provide a template file (with tables in it), the program deletes the first table and saves the document.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;

public class TableTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String filename = "template.docx";

        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream( new File( filename ) );
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument( in );

            showTablesInfo( document );

            // Deleting the first table of the document
            deleteOneTable( document, 0 );

            showTablesInfo( document );

            saveDoc( document, "template after processing.docx" );

        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            System.out.println( "File " + filename + " not found." );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println( "IOException while processing file " + filename + ":\n" + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private static void showTablesInfo( XWPFDocument document ) {
        List<XWPFTable> tables = document.getTables();
        System.out.println( "\n document has " + tables.size() + " table(s)." );

        for ( XWPFTable table : tables ) {
            System.out.println( "\t table with position #" + document.getPosOfTable( table ) + " has "
                    + table.getRows().size() + " rows" );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a table, given its relative position in document.
     */
    private static void deleteOneTable( XWPFDocument document, int tableIndex ) {
        try {
            int bodyElement = getBodyElementOfTable( document, tableIndex );
            System.out.println( "deleting table with bodyElement #" + bodyElement );
            document.removeBodyElement( bodyElement );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( "There is no table #" + tableIndex + " in the document." );
        }
    }

    private static int getBodyElementOfTable( XWPFDocument document, int tableNumberInDocument ) {
        List<XWPFTable> tables = document.getTables();
        XWPFTable theTable = tables.get( tableNumberInDocument );

        return document.getPosOfTable( theTable );
    }

    private static void saveDoc( XWPFDocument document, String filename ) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File( filename ) );
            document.write( out );
            out.close();
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println( "IOException while saving to " + filename + ":\n" + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

}
```

**Attention!** Method `removeBodyElement` of the `XWPFDocument` class has to be called outside the loop which cycles through all the document's tables. Otherwise, you risk to have `ConcurrentModificationException`, as deleting one table will affect the indices of other tables in the document.

In the above example the criteria of selecting a table to delete is simple: the first table of the document. Another way to extract the `XWPFTable` to delete, is writing a small method which will be getting, let's say, text of the first cell of the first line (title of the first column), etc. Hope this will help, good luck!