# How to delete a paragraph using XWPF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to delete a paragraph from the .docx document I have generated using the Apache poi XWPF. I can do it easily with the .doc word document using HWPF as below :

```
for (String paraCount : plcHoldrPargrafDletdLst) {
    Paragraph ph = doc.getRange().getParagraph(Integer.parseInt(paraCount));
    System.out.println("Deleted Paragraph Start & End: " + ph.getStartOffset() +" & " + ph.getEndOffset());
    System.out.println("Deleted Paragraph Test: " + ph.text());
    ph.delete();
}
```

I tried to do the same with

```
doc.removeBodyElement(Integer.parseInt(paraCount));
```

But unfortunately not successful enough to get the result as I want. The result document, I cannot see the paragraph deleted.
Any suggestions on how to accomplish the similar functionality in XWPF.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, this question is a bit old and might not be required anymore, but I just found a different solution than the suggested one.

Hope the following code will help somebody with the same issue

```
    ...
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
    fis.close();
    // Find a paragraph with todelete text inside
    XWPFParagraph toDelete = doc.getParagraphs().stream()
            .filter(p -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("todelete", p.getParagraphText()))
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
    if (toDelete != null) {
        doc.removeBodyElement(doc.getPosOfParagraph(toDelete));
        OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        doc.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I like Apache POI, and for the most part its great, however I have found the documentation a little scatty to say the least.

The elusive way of deleting a paragraph I found to be quite a nightmare, giving me the following exception error when try to remove a paragraph:

**java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**

As mention in Ugo Delle Donne example, I solved this by first recording the paragraph that I wanted to delete, and then using the **removeBodyElement** method the document.

e.g.

```
List<XWPFParagraph> record = new ArrayList<XWPFParagraph>();
String text = "";

for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()){

       text += r.text(); 
       // I saw so many examples as r.getText(pos), don't use that

       // Find some unique text in the paragraph
       //
       if (!(text==null) && (text.contains("SOME-UNIQUE-TEXT")) {               
        // Save the Paragraph to delete for later
        record.add(  p );
       }
    }
}
    

// Now delete the paragraph and anything within it.
for (int i = 0; i< record.size(); i++) {
    // Remove the Paragraph and everything within it            
    doc.removeBodyElement(doc.getPosOfParagraph(record.get(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're really unable to remove paragraphs from a .docx file.

What you should be able to do is removing the content of paragraphs... So called `Runs`.You could try with this one:

```
List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = doc.getParagraphs();

    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraph.getRuns().size(); i++)
           {
              paragraph.removeRun(i);
           }
    }
```

You can also specify which Run of which Paragraph should be removed e.g.

`paragraphs.get(23).getRuns().remove(17);`

Comment: Tried above but could not succeed. I want to delete the paragraph and not to remove the run. I will pass the position of the paragraph in the document which has to be deleted.  Other hand, i am replacing few paragraphs as below which indeed works :

Comment: List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();  
    XWPFRun r1 = paragraph.createRun(); 
    String text = paragraph.getText();
          for (XWPFRun r : runs) {  
           r.setText(remplchldr, 0);
          }            
          text = text.replace(xistPlacHoldr, EMPTY_STRING);
          r1.setText(text,0);

Comment: Deleting runs using the index and the loop you defined will delete every second run. For example, you have the runs [1,2,3,4], and then you go for i=0,1... . So you will get after removeRun(0) [2,3,4], then you removeRun(1) and get [2,4], and the loop here ends.


    while( paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0 )paragraph.removeRun(0);

is simpler and works. But it still does not remove the question's paragraph and is answered in the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

all rights reserved

```
// Remove all existing runs
removeRun(para, 0);

public static void removeRun(XWPFParagraph para, int depth)
{
    if(depth > 10)
    {
        return;
    }

    int numberOfRuns = para.getRuns().size();

    // Remove all existing runs
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRuns; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            para.removeRun(numberOfRuns - i - 1);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(para.getRuns().size() > 0)
    {
        removeRun(para, ++depth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question was answered in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968813/how-to-remove-tables-and-paragraphs-containing-data-from-docx-in-java-using-apac/http://)

When you are inside of a table you need to use the functions of the `XWPFTableCell` instead of the `XWPFDocument`:

```
cell.removeParagraph(cell.getParagraphs().indexOf(para));
```