# How to delete a particular paragraph in docx containing specific string using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to delete a particular paragraph of a document containing specific string using Apache POI. I found a piece of code in the 2nd answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44326734/8504176

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
fis.close();
// Find a paragraph with todelete text inside
XWPFParagraph toDelete = doc.getParagraphs().stream().filter(p -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("todelete", p.getParagraphText()))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
if (toDelete != null) 
  {
    doc.removeBodyElement(doc.getPosOfParagraph(toDelete));
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    doc.write(fos);
    fos.close();
 }
```

But equalsIgnoreCase() is throwing an error and I'm not getting it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous sym type:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase

How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why you need com.sun.*.StringUtils. However, try to use classical [equalsIgnoreCase(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) method from String class.

Comment: Well that worked! I used equalsIgnoreCase() instead of StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(). Thanks